# WITH VALUES TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default

I have been trying to understand what the `WITH VALUES` statement does?

I cant seem to find any documentation that explains it properly.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
ADD newGuidId UniqueIdentifier NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Guid Default newid()
with values
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`WITH VALUES` applies default values to the null fields

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187742.aspx and a [short blog post](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2009/06/ms-sql-alter-table-add-new-column-with.html) about it.

Comment: Whoever is reading this answer, please also read marc_s's answer as it provides more details.

Answer (score 76):

When you add a **nullable** column with a default constraint to a table, then all existing rows will get the new column with a `NULL` as its value. The defined default values will only be applied to **new rows** being inserted (if they don't have a value for that column in their `INSERT` statement).

When you specify `WITH VALUES`, then all existing rows will get that defined **default value** instead of `NULL`

If the column you're adding to your new table is **non-nullable** and has a default constraint, then that default value is applied to all existing rows in the table automatically (no need for `WITH VALUES` because the column must have a value other than `NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

WITH VALUES - Specifies that the value given in DEFAULT constant_expression is stored in a new column added to existing rows. If the added column allows null values and WITH VALUES is specified, the default value is stored in the new column, added to existing rows. If WITH VALUES is not specified for columns that allow nulls, the value NULL is stored in the new column in existing rows. If the new column does not allow nulls, the default value is stored in new rows regardless of whether WITH VALUES is specified.